# How do I get the inbox to stop showing me the same things over and over

Tags: support, status-bydesign, global-inbox

I bet someone will dup this and close it, but I'll learn what i need to know.

1. Pull down the notifier, since it shows (1) in the inbox.
2. Select the inbox.
3. See a very long list of items. Some of them ancient.
4. Visit the top two or three.
5. Come back to the inbox. They're all still there.

Should it ever be empty? Is there a visual distinction I'm missing between things I've seen and things I haven't?

Answer (score 5):

The inbox always* shows the 30 (number subject to change) most recent items.
The number overlay shows the number of items that have been inserted into the inbox since you last checked it, so naturally it is cleared as soon as you do.

You cannot remove items from your inbox, though they will gradually be crowded out by newer items.  This is by design.

<sub>*It is possible to "burst" above the limit, and for your inbox to be temporarily empty.  Both are very transient, and are caused by rapid activity and relatively long absences respectively.</sub>

Comment: Do you work on saturdays too?

Comment: @Juan - technically I work whenever I feel like it.

Comment: Any chance that the n unread items be highlighted differently? And have some kind of 'mark all as read' (or does just clicking on the down arrow mark them as read?